# Filter JSon Information

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am receiving JSON Data  of different forms (Not all of the json files that I will receive will have the same entries)

Usually to Parse JSon I use the dynamic class which is working if all the JSON files have the same entries but it is not working in this case.

For example for the following Data :

```
[
    {
        "Player_Name": "Zlatan Ibrahimovic",
        "Country": "Sweeden",
    },
    {
        "Player_Name": "Pavel Nedved",
        "Country": "Czech Republic",
        "Personal_Honours": 
        {
            "Ballon_DOr": "One",
        },
    }
]
```

The first two elements share the two first entries "Player_Name" and "Country" but the second element has a second entry which is "Personal_Honours"

so if I do this :

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("TextFile1.txt");
List<PlayerData> DataList;
dynamic json = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());


DataList = new List<PlayerData>();
foreach (dynamic data in json)
{
    DataList.Add(new PlayerData
    {
        Name = json.Player_Name,
        Country = json.Country , 
        BallonDor = json.Personal_Honours.Ballon_DOr
    });
}
```

with this class :

```
public class PlayerData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BallonDor {get; set; }
    public string MarketValue { get; set; }
    public string CurrentClub { get; set; }
}
```

I get a `RuntimeBinderException` since the first entry does not Contain Personal_Honours"  I will not know in advance if the JSON that will parse will contain this entry

How can I manage this error ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use concrete classes for JSON objects, you can use the power of anonymous classes: just define the sample object which use all possible properties, like this:

```
        var sample = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                Player_Name = "",
                Country = "",
                Personal_Honours = new
                {
                    Ballon_DOr = "",
                },
            }
        };
```

and use its `.GetType()` to pass to JSON deserializer like this:

```
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonString, sample.GetType());
```

Here is full working sample based on your sources:

```
internal class Program
{
    public class PlayerData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BallonDor { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string MarketValue { get; set; }
        public string CurrentClub { get; set; }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sample = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                Player_Name = "",
                Country = "",
                Personal_Honours = new
                {
                    Ballon_DOr = "",
                },
            }
        };

        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"[
{
  ""Player_Name"": ""Zlatan Ibrahimovic"",
  ""Country"": ""Sweeden"",
},
{
""Player_Name"": ""Pavel Nedved"",
 ""Country"": ""Czech Republic"",
  ""Personal_Honours"": {
  ""Ballon_DOr"": ""One"",
},
}
]", sample.GetType());

        var dataList = new List<PlayerData>();
        foreach (var data in json)
        {
            dataList.Add(
                new PlayerData
                {
                    Name = data.Player_Name,
                    Country = data.Country,
                    BallonDor = data.Personal_Honours == null ? null : data.Personal_Honours.Ballon_DOr
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my json data to add "Market_Value" to the Zlatan Ibrahimovic entry but not the other one so then I added this :                         "MarketValue = data.Market_Value == null ? null : data.Market_Value" but I have the RuntimeBinder Excepetion what went wrong?

Comment: @user2505650 `Ballon_DOr` is not part of your root object. It is a property of `Personal_Honours` class.  So forget your `PlayerData` class and think a little bit about it. Read my question again  (which shows the correct way of doing it) since I am  going to remove it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing things.

The deserilizer don't know nor it cares, how you want to save your data. It only get string to deserilize and Object type to create instance with the deserilized data.

You're mixing the first class with the second.

For example, I would devide it as follow:

```
Player class:
- Name (string)
- Country (string)
- PersonalHonours (class)

PersonalHonours class
- BallonDOr (string)
- etc..
```

Of course, in case the naming is different as in many part where '_' is different, you should "tell" the deserilizer that those in fact bind with another key by adding to that property `[JsonProperty("Ballon_DOr")]` attribute.

After all that, All you just need is use your deserilizer on the whole string and it will produce it to you ready for use.