# Dynamically Select Required JSON information

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-8

I need to deserialize some JSON but the problem is that all of my JSON objects don't have the exact same format.
Here is an example of the JSON that I have to deserialize :

```
[
  {
    "Player_Name": "Zlatan Ibrahimovic",
    "Country": "Sweeden",
    "Other_Informations": {
      "Information1": [

      ]
    },
  },
   {
    "Player_Name": "Pavel Nedved",
    "Country": "Czech Republic",
    "Personal_Honours": 
        {
            "Ballon_DOr": "One",
        },
    "Other_Informations": {
      "Information1": [

      ]
    },
  },
   {
    "Player_Name": "Zinedine Zidane",
    "Country": "Sweeden",
    "Other_Informations": {
      "Information1": [
        {
          "name": "example",
        }
      ]
    },
  }
 ]
```

As you can see, some fields appear only for some objects for example "Personal_Honours". 
I need to deserialize the JSON into this class :

```
public class PlayerData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BallonDor {get; set; }
    public string Information1{ get; set; }
    public string Country{ get; set; }
}
```

I use this method which is really long and blocks my app : 
(In this exmple I use Json that comes frome a textfile but usually  I have to make a REST request..)

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("TextFile1.txt");
List<PlayerData> DataList;
dynamic value= JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<dynamic>(reader.ReadToEnd());


DataList = new List<PlayerData>();
    foreach (dynamic data in value)
                    {

                        if (data.Personal_Honours == null)
                        {
                            if (data.Other_Informations.Information1 == null)
                            {
                                DataList.Add(new PlayerData
                                {
                                    Name = data.Player_Name,
                                    Country = data.Country,
                                });
                            }
                            else                            
                            {
                                DataList.Add(new PlayerData
                                {
                                    Name = data.Player_Name,
                                    Country = data.Country,
                                    Information1 = data.Informations.Information1
                                });

                            }

                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            if (data.Other_Informations.Information1 == null)
                            {

                                DataList.Add(new PlayerData
                                {
                                    Name = data.Player_Name,
                                    Country = data.Country,
                                    BallonDor = data.Personal_Honours.Ballon_DOr

                                });
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                DataList.Add(new PlayerData
                                {
                                    Name = data.Player_Name,
                                    Country = data.Country,
                                    BallonDor = data.Personal_Honours.Ballon_DOr,
                                    Information1 = data.Informations.Information1

                                });

                            }

                        }

                    }
```

This method is working but it is not efficient and  blocks my UI. 
How can I do to create a  new "PlayerData"  object without having all of those   'else if'  statements ?
Thank you !

P.S : The question is different from this one [Filter JSon Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333729/filter-json-information)

EDIT :

Here is how I got the RunTimeBinderExcepetion :

```
 List<PlayerData> datalist = new List<PlayerData>();

    foreach (dynamic pl in timeline)
    {



        datalist.Add(new PlayerData 
        { 

         Name  = pl.Player_Name , 
         Country = pl.Country ,
          BallonDor = pl.Personal_Honours.Ballon_Dor,
           Information1 = pl.Other_Informations.Information1.name

        });
    }
```

Comment: If you're using Newtonsoft (which it looks like you are) you can deserialize JSON that doesn't match every field. On fields that don't match they will simply be null. So you should be able to skip the entire deserialize to `dynamic` and deserialize directly to your `PlayerData` type.

Comment: I tried to do this but got a 'RuntimeBinderException' can you please provide a quick code of your example?

Comment: Can you post the code where you got a RuntimeBinderException. Might be able to figure out issue a bit more easily then.

Comment: `This method is working but it is not efficient and blocks my UI` I can't believe it unless your json is many GB

Comment: well it does, i only provided a short sample but i get a lot more of JSON, i made my tests with a Lumia 920

Comment: @user2505650 you can create your classes using [this site](http://json2csharp.com/). As *siva.k*'s said, you will have only the maching fields. But I repeat it again, how much time do you think an *if* takes? Your problem must be somewhere else you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got exception because some data doesn't have `Personal_Honours` property for example. Then you tried to access `Ballon_Dor` property from a `null` reference which trigger the exception. This way will work for sample JSON you posted :

```
List<PlayerData> datalist = new List<PlayerData>();
foreach (dynamic pl in timeline)
{
    //object initialization is done later just for the sake of easier debugging
    //...so we can spot unexpected data which cause exception easily
    var Name = pl.Player_Name;
    var Country = pl.Country;
    var BallonDor = pl.Personal_Honours != null ? pl.Personal_Honours.Ballon_Dor : null;
    var Information1 = pl.Other_Informations.Information1.Count > 0 ? 
                                pl.Other_Informations.Information1[0].name : 
                                null;
    datalist.Add(new PlayerData 
    { 
        Name  = Name , 
        Country = Country ,
        BallonDor = BallonDor,
        Information1 = Information1
    });
}
```

...but above approach is still error prone depending on how consistent is the JSON string we have. More robust approach is maybe to have model classes to map JSON string as suggested by @L.B in comment.

Comment: I Used L.B's approach and it is working thank you ! now I am trying to make it async !